# How to escape Javascript in an XQuery function

Tags: javascript, xquery, marklogic

Is there a way to escape or render Javascript in a xquery function?

**Example:**

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
module namespace tagmanager = "tagmanager";
declare function tagmanager() { < noscript > < iframe src = "//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=[value]"
    height = "0"
    width = "0"
    style = "display:none;visibility:hidden" > < /iframe></noscript >
        < script > (function(w, d, s, l, i) {
            w[l] = w[l] || [];
            w[l].push({
                'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
                event: 'gtm.js'
            });
            var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j = d.createElement(s),
                dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
            j.async = true;
            j.src =
                '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
            f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
        })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'value'); < /script>
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always used the approach of escaping problematic characters and treating the HTML as well-formed XML:

(1) escape the problematic characters like ampersands (`&` > `&amp;`) and curly braces, which just need to be doubled: `{` > `{{` and `}` > `}}`

(2) if serving up multiple elements, create a sequence: `(<element1/>, <element2/>)`

Applying that approach to this example:

```
(
<noscript> 
    <iframe src = "//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=[value]"
        height = "0"
        width = "0"
        style = "display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>,
<script> (function(w, d, s, l, i) {{
        w[l] = w[l] || [];
        w[l].push({{
            'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
            event: 'gtm.js'
        }});
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j = d.createElement(s),
            dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&amp;l=' + l : '';
        j.async = true;
        j.src =
            '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    }})(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'value');
</script>
)
```

That said, I like the CDATA approach - had never occurred to me before!

Comment: I prefer the solution by joewiz, however it can be problematic because the result is xhtml not html.  When I write html apps in XQuery I always (try to) use xhtml because it 'just makes more sense' - and typically works, but there are some issues.   To get it portable you should include the right DOCTYPE in the header.   Some elements in HTML work differently (essentially are errors) if represented in xhtml such as <br> which have no end tags, a <br/> and <br></br> can be rendered differently, similarly with <p> vs <p>xxx</p>  ... the benefit its easier to embed xquery expressions.

Comment: Agreed about the mismatch between XHTML and HTML. Some XQuery implementations support the XQuery Serialization spec, which has an HTML output type - see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-30/#html-output - which does the right thing with `<br/>`, `<script></script>`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

CDATA content does not need escaping.
The example is obtuse because your generating HTML in an XML lanaguge,  I suggest treating the whole thing as a string.
Explicit CDATA constructor is only allowed withing an element so you need a wrapper.
http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#doc-xquery-CDataSectionContents

Example:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
declare function local:tagmanager() as xs:string 
{ 
<wrapper> 
<![CDATA[
< noscript > < iframe src = "//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=[value]"
    height = "0"
    width = "0"
    style = "display:none;visibility:hidden" > < /iframe></noscript >
        < script > (function(w, d, s, l, i) {
            w[l] = w[l] || [];
            w[l].push({
                'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
                event: 'gtm.js'
            });
            var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j = d.createElement(s),
                dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
            j.async = true;
            j.src =
                '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
            f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
        })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'value'); < /script>


]]>
</wrapper>/string()
};

 local:tagmanager()
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to put the JavaScript in a text file read with a separate request (which is also beneficial for browser caching).

Another is to use a CDATA section for the content of an element, as in:

However, you still have to use ampersand escapes for the reserved characters ( < > ' " &) within the CDATA section.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  When I tried the CDATA I still get errors?  Can you give an example of using ampersand escapes?